# Sync all the ids from an array

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I need a little help with this one.

I have a `documents` array which looks like this.

[image]

What I am looking for is to simply `sync` all the ids with an existing pivot table.

```
if($request->has('documents')) 
   {
    $arr = [];

    foreach ($data['documents'] as  $value) {

      $arr[] = $value->id // ain't doing the trick; error "Trying to get property of non-object"
    }
      //var_dump($arr);
     $jig->documents()->sync($arr);
  }
```

I understand that `sync()` method takes an array.

```
$arr = [1,2,3];
```

How can I turn the ids in the `documents` array into something like this?

Thanks for your time!

**Update #1** Based on comment.

dumping the values in `foreach`

```
    array(8) {
  ["id"]=>
  int(5)
  ["name"]=>
  string(13) "Reyna Bartell"
  ["description"]=>
  string(4) "Cum."
  ["relative_path"]=>
  string(9) "Voluptas."
  ["created_by"]=>
  NULL
  ["created_at"]=>
  string(19) "2016-12-28 14:27:58"
  ["updated_at"]=>
  string(19) "2016-12-28 14:27:58"
  ["updated_by"]=>
  NULL
}
array(8) {
  ["id"]=>
  int(6)
  ["name"]=>
  string(20) "Ms. Abigail Schaefer"
  ["description"]=>
  string(4) "Aut."
  ["relative_path"]=>
  string(4) "Quo."
  ["created_by"]=>
  NULL
  ["created_at"]=>
  string(19) "2016-12-28 14:27:58"
  ["updated_at"]=>
  string(19) "2016-12-28 14:27:58"
  ["updated_by"]=>
  NULL
}
```

Comment: What is `$data['documents']`? Shouldn't that be `$request->documents`?

Comment: @Loek Yeah that does it as well. That's not the point though. Just testing things here. I will refactor later.

Comment: Can you dump (one of) the values in your foreach loop and add them to your question? Cause your code looks fine to me

Comment: @Loek Updated.  var_dump($value); in the foreach returned the above. 2 arrays, which is not going to work. This is why I am looking for a way to extract only the ids and store those into an array like this $arr = [1,2.3].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `$value` in your foreach loop is in fact an array as your dump suggests:

```
// Change this line
$arr[] = $value->id;

// To this
$arr[] = $value['id'];
```

The error thrown ("Trying to get property of non-object") confirms that `$value` is in fact an array, so this should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_map()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) function. For example

```
$myIds = array_map(function($v) {
    return $v['id'];
}, $data['documents']);
```

However, this will return you an array like this

```
// var_export($myIds)
array(
    0 => 5
    1 => 6,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the power of [Laravel collections](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections) instead of manually rebuilding one array to another:

```
if ($request->has('documents')) {
   $jig->documents()->sync(collect($request->documents)->pluck('id'));
}
```